# Validating attachment contents on upload with Paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Paperclip has validator methods for validating the presence, size, and content-type of files. But is there a way to validate the *contents* of the file before the record is saved?

I tried doing `validate :my_method` and opening the file from `[attachment].path` in `my_method`, but of course that fails because the attachment hasn't been moved to its final resting place in the file system before the record is saved.

Writing a custom Paperclip post-processor seemed like an option because it has access to the File object belonging to the attachment before the record is saved, but a failing processor won't invalidate the record before it's saved.

Is there a good way to do this? How else can I make sure that I only have conforming files living in my app? (Are there other callbacks I can use that will gracefully delete the entire record if the file isn't valid?)

edit: Ooh. In particular, will raising ActiveRecord::Rollback from an after_save callback do something sane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah, but you *can* access the File object from a validator before the record is saved, by calling `[attachment].to_file`. Running my parser against `[attachment].to_file.path` (instead of `attachment.path`) in `my_method` seems to work just fine.

Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047183/how-to-set-an-attribute-for-a-model-instance-in-a-paperclip-post-process-callback, `[attachment].queued_for_write[:original].path` might also be an option.

Comment: Actually only the second version [attachment].queued_for_write[:original].path worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and perhaps someone who has experience with this can give you a better answer, but given that there doesn't appear to be a way to do this within the DSL provided by Paperclip, I would recommend just building your own Paperclip *validator* (not post-processor).

You can use [an existing validator](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/matchers/validate_attachment_content_type_matcher.rb) as an example, and drop it into `app/lib/paperclip/matchers/validate_foobar.rb` (be sure to set your `config/application.rb` to load from your `lib` folder) and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for this. After starting to dig in, I stumbled across a way to access the file before commitment in my own model after all. Cheers!

Comment: Tim--can you update your question with what you've figured out, please? I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: @andymism: He posted a separate answer.

Comment: (Is that the proper etiquette? I'm new here.)

Comment: @Tim Smith: Yup! You're welcome to accept your own answer too. You don't see it often, but you can even add multiple answers to a question (maybe one now, one in a year when you've discovered something new). Welcome!