# Get absolute path/location of file to be imported + the file name - Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, csv, paperclip

I'm uploading excel files to my application using `paperclip` gem. Before uploading I would like to check the `header column names` for its presence. So, I need to open the document using its path and read the header contents. But since we are doing it before the importing process, we should open it from the path being accessed rather than from the path where we upload the paperclip files.

E.g.,

Assume that I'm uploading a file from `'/home/user/rajesh/Test1.xlsx'` and paperclip will upload it to `'/home/user/rajesh/Project/public/system/000/000/001/Test1.xlsx'`. So, I need to get the value `'/home/user/rajesh/Test1.xlsx'`.

Code:

```
if File.extname(importfile.file_file_name) == ".csv"
  spreadsheet = Roo::Csv.new(importfile.file.path, nil, :ignore)
elsif File.extname(importfile.file_file_name) == ".xls"
  spreadsheet = Roo::Excel.new(importfile.file.path, nil, :ignore)
elsif File.extname(importfile.file_file_name) == ".xlsx"
  spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(importfile.file.path, nil, :ignore)
else
  raise "Unknown file type for '#{importfile.file_file_name}'"
end
```

But, `importfile.file.path` is not returning the correct path.

So, how we can get that absolute path to a file along with the file name? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `importfile.file.path` returning?

Comment: @Matthew: `file /home/user/rajesh/Project/public/system/import_files/files//original/Test2.xlsx does not exist`, because this is trying to call the paperclip uploaded path.

Comment: I would take a look at `files//original`. Have you looked at your paperclip config to make sure you're not using a nil value to build your path?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your issue has nothing to do with `paperclip`, and I think the browser never sends the local path to the file when using a file upload.

What prevents you from checking the attachment before running the import?

Comment: I want to trigger a model validation using :before_save to check the header columns. How that is possible?

Comment: [This accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044645/validating-attachment-contents-on-upload-with-paperclip-gem) has what you need.